# Postgresql bulk retrieval

Tags: postgresql, date

Currently I have a query that outputs some sort of performance index based on the date range selected. For example, by choosing 1st Jan 2017 to 6th Jan 2017, it gives me the performance of all the workers over this period aggregating their scores from these few days. Something like this:

```
Rank|Name|Score
1   |Tom |98
2   |Sam |87
3   |Sab |88
```

That is if I select that particular date range. The score changes from time to time as the date range changes. Right now, how it works is on 7th Jan, I am interested in his performance one week prior (1st Jan - 6th Jan), so the current query requires me to manually select the date range if I want to have the data for each day. Ideally now I would love to have a huge list of data looking at performances over a huge date range, 1 December 16 - 1st March 17. E.g. from each day of this range, I obtain the score 1 week prior. I would love to be able to generate this data by selecting this date range instead so it should look something like this:

```
Rank|Name|Score|Date of Reference
1   |Tom |91   |1st Dec (Looks at data from 24th to 30th Nov)
2   |Sam |83   |1st Dec (Looks at data from 24th to 30th Nov)
3   |Sab |85   |1st Dec (Looks at data from 24th to 30th Nov)
1   |Tom |81   |2nd Dec (Looks at data from 25th Nov to 1st Dec)
2   |Sam |66   |2nd Dec (Looks at data from 25th Nov to 1st Dec)
3   |Sab |90   |2nd Dec (Looks at data from 25th Nov to 1st Dec)
1   |Tom |34   |3rd Dec (Looks at data from 26th Nov to 2nd Dec)
2   |Sam |50   |3rd Dec (Looks at data from 26th Nov to 2nd Dec)
3   |Sab |98   |3rd Dec (Looks at data from 26th Nov to 2nd Dec)
so on and so forth till 1st March
```

The restriction I have now is I can only select the date ranges for one week. and then download these files one by one which is extremely time consuming.

Comment: Are you using mysql or postgress? Please tag appropriately.

Comment: Post sample data

Comment: postgresql. Sorry I know this is hard for visualization but I can't post any sample data due to some sensitivity issues. But what I've reproduced above is extremely close.